# How to split an Angular service into several services

Tags: angular, typescript, service

So I have a service in angular that is growing from the birth of the application. My intention is to split the service into different smaller services that handle specific logic.

### **Originally:**

car.service.ts (Huge service)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CarService {

engine: any
started: boolean;
lights: any;
speed: number;

  constructor() { }

// HUGE AMOUNT OF CODE

 ......

}
```

### **GOAL:**

-car.service.ts (with common information)

- *engine.service.ts
- *lights.service.ts

Car service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CarService {

engine: any // Shared variable between services
speed: number;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Engine service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EngineService {

engine: any // Comes in any way from car service
started:boolean;

  constructor() { }

   start() {
   // start the car
   }
}
```

Lights service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LightsService {

engine: any // Comes in any way from car service
lightsOn :boolean;
intensity: number;

  constructor() { }

   turnLights() {
   // turns the lights on/off
   }
}
```

So the question here is how to share that common information (on car.service.ts) such as global variables between the different new services?

Should I use some kind of inheritance between services? Or maybe set some special configuration in a common module between them?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is hierarchical, e.g. you do not use say `LightsService` in `EngineService`, then you can simply inject one service into another:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LightsService {

engineService: EngineService; // Comes in any way from car service
lightsOn :boolean;
intensity: number;

  constructor(engineService: EngineService) { }

   turnLights() {
   // turns the lights on/off
   }
}
```

This way it is not possible to use `LightsService` in `EngineService` and `EngineService` in `LightsService` at the same time because it causes circular references.

Another possible approach is to have full model (data e.g. engine, lights etc) in a single service and inject it to all other "action" services.